# anchor tag to call pop up Modal Box without bootstrap not working?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a table with each row has link of  tag "click here", I want to use a modal box to pop up when a user click on the link and display all row information and allow user to make edit and update.

[image]

I am using AJAX with JQuery to pass row id, which is used at backend with PHP to execute SQL Query.

But i don't want to use Bootstrap Modal Box. Please help in making a modal box pop up or something other so that user can make edits on each row of displayed table when a user click on `<td><p><a href='' id='%d' value='%d'>Click here</a></p></td>`.

I am not clear with how to use Modal Box for each row. may be that could be easier using Jquery.

Below is code of `<section>` tag of my `Dashboard.html` which has table.

**Here focus on `<td><p><a href='' id='%d' value='%d'>Click here</a></p></td>`**. which include button to call modal box.

```
<!-- View All Added Campaign and Lead information -->

<section class="operation" id="view_all_lead_Campaign" style="width: 100%;margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
    <!-- Main Tables Campaign and Lead Table                        -->

    <div class="row">

        <!-- MAIN TABLE-->

        <div class="col" >

            <button class="viewMainTable" name='viewMainTable' onclick='viewMainTable();' id='viewMainTableButton' >Lead Table</button>

            <button class="viewCampaignTable" name='viewCampaignTable' onclick='viewCampaignTable();' id='viewCampaignTableButton' >View Campaign Table</button>              


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-4-of-4">                                

                    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">

                        <table class="display_table" id='main_lead_table' style="display: none;">

                            <thead>                        
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Lead Id</th> 
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Website</th>
                                <th>Linkedin</th>
                                <th>Lead Description</th>
                                <th>Owner Notes</th>                                
                                <th>Last Contact Date</th>
                                <th>Next Contact Date</th>
                                <th>Lead Status</th> 
                                <th>Details</th>

                            </thead>

                            <tbody id='leadTable'>                          

                                <?php



                                function getLeadAddedByName($id){

                                    include('./server/connection.php');

                                    $selectSQL = "SELECT UserName FROM `tbl_user_signup_info` WHERE User_Id = '$id' ";

                                    $result = $conn -> query ($selectSQL);

                                    $name = "";

                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                                    $name = $row['UserName'];

                                    }

                                    return $name;

                                }

                                include('./server/connection.php'); 

                                $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_main_lead_info` ORDER BY Lead_Id";

                                $result = $conn -> query ($selectSQL);

                                $i = 1;

                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {                                   


                                              printf( "<tr class='content'>
                                                            <td>%s</td>
                                                            <td>%s</td>

                                                            <td>%s</td> 

                                                            <td>%s</td>                                                               

                                                            <td>%s</td>
                                                            <td>%s</td>
                                                            <td>%s</td>
                                                            <td>%s</td>

                                                            <td>%s</td>                                                                      
                                                            <td>%s</td>
                                                            <td>%s</td>
                                                            <td>%s</td>

                                                            <td><p><a href='' id='%d' value='%d'>Click here</a></p></td>   
                                                        </tr>",

                                                        $i,
                                                        $row['Lead_Id'], 
                                                        $row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName'],
                                                        $row['Website'],
                                                        $row['Linkedin'],
                                                        $row['LeadDescription'],
                                                        $row['OwnerNotes'],                                                       

                                                        $row['AdminNotes'],

                                                        getLeadAddedByName($row['LeadAddedBy'])."<br>Date/Time: ".$row['LeadAddedOn'],                                                                                                             

                                                        date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['LastContactDate'])),
                                                        date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['NextContactDate'])),                                                          
                                                        $row['LeadStatus'],

                                                        $row['Lead_Id'],
                                                        $row['Lead_Id'],

                                                        );

                                                $i = $i+1;

                                            }

                                ?>                                       

                            </tbody>                           

                        </table> 

                        </div>                                                          

                    </div>                       
                </div>                         

            </div>                              

        </div>

</section>
```

`Modal.js` file to get the click here id and correspoding that PHP at backend execute to fetch record and populate in Modal Box Pop up.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 


    $('[name="leadidclick"]').click(function(e){

      e.preventDefault();
      var leadid = $('[name="leadidclick"]').val();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: './server/modal.php',
        data: {
          'leadid': leadid
        },        
        success: function(data){

           var result = $.parseJSON(data);
           console.log(result);

           //Modal Box to POP UP HERE


        }


      });



    });

});
```

My `Modal.php` file for backend

```
<?php

// send a JSON encoded array to client

include('./server/connection.php');

/* check connection */
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if( $_POST['campaignid'] != "" ) {

    // echo "Modal.php file is executed";

    $id = $_POST['campaignid'];

    $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM  `tbl_main_lead_info` WHERE Lead_Id = '$id' ";

    $result_array = array();

    $result = $conn -> query ($selectSQL);

    // If there are results from database push to result array

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            array_push($result_array, $row);

        }

    }

    echo json_encode($result_array);

}else{

    echo $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: I am also trying this link (http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-modal-tutorial/)  but don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Add a Modal in the page.

Step 2:

Upon click of the anchor element pass the id to ajax function and fetch record

Step 3:

create the form at either **php** or **jquery** side.

and show modal with the final response.

1. **At PHP**

   *response from server will have form ready with data, you just need to add the response to modal-body div.*

```
$.ajax({
    url :: 'your url',
    type : 'post',
    data : {id: row id},
    success: function(response){
        $('.modal-body').html(response);
        $('#your-modal-id').modal('show');
    }
});
```

2. **At Jquery side**

```
$.ajax({
    url :: 'your url',
    type : 'post',
    data : {id: row id},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(response){
        //here inside json variable you've the json returned by your PHP
        for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
            $('#form-element').val(json[i].item_name);
            .
            .
            .
        }
        $('#your-modal-id').modal('show');

    }
});
```

Please note: there are many ways to do it, if you find it complex, feel free to write, I will try to give you exact solution. :)

Comment: I appreciate your effort thanks I am also trying this link http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-modal-tutorial/

Comment: i am facing main issue at this `create the form at either php or jquery side.`, also new to modal box pop up

Comment: There are more number of modal i need to pop up based on the number of rows in the HTML table. as each row has click here and which pop up each table row in a modal box

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.

I will be available after 2 hours.



Modal will be only one, only the data will dynamically change.

Case 1, if you are processing data at php level, there you can prepare the html form with data and directly send as ajax response.

Case 2, using jquery if you are parsing json, then you can iterate the data in the SAME form.

In both the cases, the form will remain same, only data will change.

if you need help on php or jquery side, lemme know.

Comment: One more thing - 

In your modal.php, near echo `json_encode($result_array);`

instead of encoding it, make the form here and use the result_array values to populate the form and send the final html to ajax

Comment: Thanks for help, I try for building the HTML form at PHP or AJAX.

Comment: There are lot of things moving around 1) Modal Box in div tag in HTML file (with 'click here' option) and that need to get the form body. 2) with click on 'click here' javascript file gets the row id and send to PHP file. 3) PHP file execute the SQL query to get the row information in HTML Form with form Id same as my row id, and send the result/response to the JS file.

Comment: The JS File just put the respone in div and changes its CSS property to display the Modal Box Pop up.

Comment: Populating the form at php will be easy for you.

Just pass the id of that row, and fetch the record.

Render the html form with fetched data and echo $html

Directly receive it in ajax, fill this received response in the .modal-body .

Lemme know if you need direct solution. I can prepare whole code for you if you want.

Comment: I have posted some of my code, and earlier i am receiving JSON code but now i am getting console error, please check if you can, i pasted updated code there (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59764551/button-id-change-is-not-detected-by-js-code?noredirect=1#comment105674455_59764551) .

Comment: Can you expand the json response just above the red texts. >[{....}]

and share the response as well.

Comment: That JSON response is correct for the lead id and also i separated JS file for each different click. I will update the screenshot

Comment: I think there is minor syntax error,

try to print data in console first then result.

share the snapshot, if you have a temp hosting, put it there and share the link. 

This is very easy but it needs access to the code and setup.

Comment: I updated the question at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59764551/button-id-change-is-not-detected-by-js-code?noredirect=1#comment105674455_59764551)

Comment: Data is fetched properly, next check compaignmodal.js:20

click and see where it is highlighting the error.

and also use JSON.parse instead of parseJson

Comment: The problem is solved by making 3 separate js and 3 separate PHP file and i am getting JSON object for all click and Now main problem left is MOdal box pop up with Form having values of that JSON.

Comment: This is not a problem, if you have data ready, then u just need to pick the correct selector and attach the correct data to it.

Show me how you are handling this.

- Share your form html
- Share your success:function(data){ ..... }

Comment: And i do not think, making separate file is the solution, will check that later, lets first fix you issue.

will cleanup your code later.

Comment: Yes sure i share you my code once i try for FORM Pop up, if i face any issue